# Visual Studio 2010 Database Unit Testing - Continue running tests after an error

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing

Visual Studio 2010 Database Unit Testing

I have unit tests that run great as expected.  However, I want to test those cases that should throw an error (ex. insert char where expecting an int) but when I run a bunch of tests the unit tests stop as soon as it hits an error (that I am obviously expecting) from the DB (SQL Server 2008-R2).

How can I set VS to continue running the rest of the tests?  on a side note, should I even be testing for these types of cases?